# How to add a delay in reading data in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently doing a project that displays markers in google maps. My Firebase database contains the coordinates for the markers. I've used Thread.sleep but it freezes the entire app. I'm currently trying handler, here's my code:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    ref.child("tuofu").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Ship p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Ship.class);
                bearing = p.getBearing();
                latitude = p.getLatitude();
                longitude = p.getLongitude();
                mmsi = String.valueOf(p.getMmsi());
                name = p.getName();
                speed = p.getSpeed();
                entrynumber = p.getEntrynumber();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(name).snippet(String.valueOf(entrynumber)));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom((sydney), 15));
                    }
                }, 3000);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



}
```

This code only displays the last data in the database. 
And this code:

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    ref.child("tuofu").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Ship p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Ship.class);
                        bearing = p.getBearing();
                        latitude = p.getLatitude();
                        longitude = p.getLongitude();
                        mmsi = String.valueOf(p.getMmsi());
                        name = p.getName();
                        speed = p.getSpeed();
                        entrynumber = p.getEntrynumber();
                        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(name).snippet(String.valueOf(entrynumber)));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom((sydney), 15));
                    }
                }, 3000);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Displays all the data but the delay doesn't work. This produces the same result in a code where I don't put handler. What did I do wrong with the handler? How can I make it work?

Thanks for the help.

**The questions in the similar questions tab have problems encountering unwanted delays, In mine, I want to add a delay** (I might get flagged with having a similar question)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a Handler to have delay in your project`enter code here`

achieve using below code.

```
  int delayTime=3*1000; //ss *mm 

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


            @Override
                public void run() {
                    // call function
                }
            },delayTime);
```